# Why doesn't the UIBarButtonItem observe the HIG?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uibarbuttonitem

According to the Human Interface Guidelines, a touch target should be no smaller than 44x44 points. But a `UIBarButtonItem`, which many common action such as navigation rely on, is only about 20x20 points.

Is there any reason for this (other than the fact that these are 'guidelines')? Will my app be rejected if I use a similar sized button where I feel it is appropriate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The touch area of a UIBarButtonItem is much bigger than the size of the icon. So it is not violating the HIG.

Your app is not likely to get rejected if you have a button with a touch area that is smaller than 44x44 but it will be harder for a user to use. I've used plenty of apps with tiny touch areas. Make it bigger if you can, don't when you can't.

Comment: Well how about that - I checked on the simulator and the button does indeed respond when I touch a few pixels above/below. I will follow the same model, assuming that there is no overlap with neighboring controls.

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer if it answers your question.

Comment: Was just waiting for the timer to let me